# What to do you after a cat dies?

Tags: cats, death

I've tried googling online about what you do with the body and who you contact, but i haven't gotten clear answers.

What to do you after a cat dies?
Who do you contact and what happens to the body?

Answer (score 1):

Your veterinary hospital will have the resources to proceed with disposing a body. They can either provide you contact information or take your pet and register him with them for you.

There are a few options:

1) If bi-laws permit, bury him in your back yard (3-4 feet deep minimum).

2) Common burial - this will be done by the cremation service in your area.

3) Common Cremation - Cremated with other pets, no ashes will be returned.

4) Private Cremation - expensive, cremated alone and ashes will be returned.

5) Pet Cemetery - usually done by the cremation service.

Comment: There are Private Cremation service available in our area for about $300 for small pets. I would not describe this as very expensive.

Comment: Ours its about that too, though I find it expensive lol especially since common cremation is about 30$